# multiple grouping of documents with nested array and then all group limit in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have document which contains array named items on inside document which contains 3 location 1st location - mumbai 2nd - london End 3rd - Delhi and all of them their famous street

```
"id": "1",
"category": "education",
"field": "science",
"items": [
{
"location": "mumbai",
"street": "Marine Drive"
},
{
"location": "mumbai",
"street": "Linking Road"
},
{
"location": "london",
"street": "Oxford Street"
},
{
"location": "mumbai",
"street": "Bruce Street"
},
{
"location": "delhi",
"street": "Chandni Chowk"
},
{
"location": "london",
"street": "Carnaby Street"
},
{
"location": "london",
"street": "King's Road"
},

]
```

this is my code i want more efficient way to do that

```
   aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$items"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        location: "$items.location"
      },
      street: {
        $push: "$items.street"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      location: "$_id.location",
      street: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$street",
          as: "street",
          cond: {
            $lt: [
              {
                $indexOfArray: [
                  "$street",
                  "$$street"
                ]
              },
              2
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

using mongodb aggregation in nodejs i want only 2 street name at a time through limit(). in all of location.

## expected output

```
"items": [
{
"location": "mumbai",
"street": [
"Marine Drive",
"Linking Road",

]
},
{
"location": "london",
"street": [
"Oxford Street",
"Carnaby Street"
]
},
{

"location": "delhi",
"street": [
"Chandni Chowk",
]
}
]
```

Comment: How will you determine which 2 streets to include for each?

Comment: The code you show will **not** work with the document you show.  There is no `"title"` nor `"value"` field in the document.

Comment: please check i was edited my code